# How to get the rolling cummulative count in the last 5 rows?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe for which I need to calculate the rolling cummulative count on the current variable. I just did this in excel ( yellow column ). How can I do the same in pandas without using loop as there are many big files where I need to do the same calculation

[image]

```
      Date_time   Close    Color
0   2015-01-09  18598.05    Red
1   2015-01-12  18808.75    Green
2   2015-01-13  18724.75    Red
3   2015-01-14  18636.85    Red
4   2015-01-15  19134.65    Green
5   2015-01-19  19401.45    Green
6   2015-01-20  19761.10    Green
7   2015-01-21  19819.90    Green
8   2015-01-22  19931.65    Green
9   2015-01-23  20051.80    Green
```

I hope this dataframe fulfils the purpose. The information is just one of sample information. In other files I might be having multiple unique values and is not limited to 2 ( red and green in this case )

Comment: You should post your data (and only relevant data) as text, not pictures.

Comment: Why does the count not increment on every row when the color is the same?

Comment: `np.sum([df['Color'].shift(i+1).eq(df['Color']) for i in range(5)])`

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: at first read notice : [mre]. we need minimal reproducible example and desired output of input in text and explanation of the logic. also you are asking code of python,  but
 you explain logic in Excel functions is not the best way to get helpful answers.

Comment: Please also add your expected output for the sample data you have provided, and an explanation as to how the output is generated.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

if there are only 2 color (green & red), use following code:

```
cond = df['Color'].eq('Red')
s = cond.rolling(5).sum().shift()
df['Color_count'] = s.where(cond, s.rsub(5))
```

df

```
   Date_time     Close  Color  Color_count
0  2015-01-09  18598.05    Red          NaN
1  2015-01-12  18808.75  Green          NaN
2  2015-01-13  18724.75    Red          NaN
3  2015-01-14  18636.85    Red          NaN
4  2015-01-15  19134.65  Green          NaN
5  2015-01-19  19401.45  Green          2.0
6  2015-01-20  19761.10  Green          3.0
7  2015-01-21  19819.90  Green          3.0
8  2015-01-22  19931.65  Green          4.0
9  2015-01-23  20051.80  Green          5.0
```

---

**Update**

if there are many color, use following code:

```
import numpy as np    
tmp = pd.get_dummies(df['Color']).rolling(5).sum().shift()

condlist = [df['Color'].eq(color) for color in df['Color'].unique()]
choicelist = [tmp[color] for color in df['Color'].unique()]
df['Color_choice'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

df:

```
    Date_time     Close  Color  Color_choice
0  2015-01-09  18598.05    Red           NaN
1  2015-01-12  18808.75  Green           NaN
2  2015-01-13  18724.75    Red           NaN
3  2015-01-14  18636.85    Red           NaN
4  2015-01-15  19134.65  Green           NaN
5  2015-01-19  19401.45  Green           2.0
6  2015-01-20  19761.10  Green           3.0
7  2015-01-21  19819.90  Green           3.0
8  2015-01-22  19931.65  Green           4.0
9  2015-01-23  20051.80  Green           5.0
```

This is just a loop over numbers of color, and the rest are vectorized operations, so it shouldn't take too long.

chk with new example

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = list('RGBRGBBBRRRGB')
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Color'])
```

result:

```
   Color  Color_choice
0      R           NaN
1      G           NaN
2      B           NaN
3      R           NaN
4      G           NaN
5      B           1.0
6      B           2.0
7      B           3.0
8      R           1.0
9      R           1.0
10     R           2.0
11     G           0.0
12     B           1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this is just a sample file. Unique number of items in a column can be anything and is not limited to 2

Comment: Apologies for this

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `str.get_dummies()` and `join()`

```
(df.rename_axis('index')
.join(
    df['Color'].str.get_dummies()
    .rolling(5,min_periods=1).sum()
    .shift()
    .fillna(0)
    .stack()
    .rename('Color_count')
    ,on = ['index','Color'])
    )
```

Output:

```
        Date_time     Close  Color  Color_count
index                                          
0      2015-01-09  18598.05    Red          0.0
1      2015-01-12  18808.75  Green          0.0
2      2015-01-13  18724.75    Red          1.0
3      2015-01-14  18636.85    Red          2.0
4      2015-01-15  19134.65  Green          1.0
5      2015-01-19  19401.45  Green          2.0
6      2015-01-20  19761.10  Green          3.0
7      2015-01-21  19819.90  Green          3.0
8      2015-01-22  19931.65  Green          4.0
9      2015-01-23  20051.80  Green          5.0
```